# PHP parse XML file with grouping

Tags: php, xml, html-table, simplexml

I have the following xml code from a library source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <MyData>
    <Column Collections="Books.ID">
      <Row>1534</Row>
      <Row>2753</Row>
      <Row>3734</Row>
      <Row>4029</Row>
      <Row>5242</Row>
      <Row>6833</Row>
      <Row>7275</Row>
      <Row>8456</Row>
    </Column>
    <Column Collections="Books.InStock">
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
    </Column>
    <Column Collections="Books.HowMany">
      <Row>12</Row>
      <Row>4</Row>
      <Row>19</Row>
      <Row>2</Row>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Row>18</Row>
      <Row>52</Row>
      <Row>26</Row>
      <Row>32</Row>
      <Row>4</Row>
    </Column>
  </MyData>
 </Data>
```

How can I put that data into a html table with SimpleXML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) over `SimpleXML`, as it's easier to use without all the magic. But effectively they can both do the same thing to meet your needs here.

What you're trying to do is take all of the `Column` nodes to get their column names (i.e. the `Collections` attribute) and put them in a list.

Then you need to get all the rows of the table by building a transposed matrix of the `Row` nodes from their respective `Column` parent nodes.

Here's a simple example of how to do that.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($xmlFileName); // load the XML into the DOM

// get all column names
$columnNames = [];
$columns = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Column');
foreach($columns as $column) {
  $columnNames[] = $column->getAttribute("Collections");
}

// get all rows by column [i.e. cells]
$rows = [];
foreach($columns as $c => $column) {
  foreach($column->getElementsByTagName('Row') as $r => $row) {
    $rows[$r][$c] = $row->nodeValue;
  }
}
```

## Printing out the HTML

Now you can just print out the HTML table like this.

```
// print out the HTML table
echo "<table>";

echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columnNames as $columnName) { // the thead
  echo "<th>$columnName</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($rows as $row) { // the tbody
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($row as $column) {
    echo "<td>$column</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Wow so much easier that way! Thanks a lot it works like a charm!

Comment: I couldn't disagree more about DOM vs SimpleXML, although in this case the code would be virtually identical anyway, just a bit shorter: `$dom->getElementsByTagName('Column');` becomes `$sx->Column`,`$column->getAttribute("Collections")` becomes `(string)$column["Collections"]`, and `$row->nodeValue` becomes `(string)$row`.